# Datasource issue with EJB

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

Been having a couple of problems getting my EJB to work correctly - finally managed to get my JBoss server working well with Netbeans and now im getting the following error which seems to be something to do with my datasource:

Server Log below:

```
2012-03-11 19:05:11,181 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] (HDScanner) undeploy, ctxPath=/group4_Implementation-war
2012-03-11 19:05:12,373 INFO  [org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandler] (WorkerThread#0[127.0.0.1:30606]) invoke, payload: {DeploymentTargetID=names=[group4_Implementation.ear], clientAddress=/127.0.0.1}, parameter: start
2012-03-11 19:05:12,374 WARN  [org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandler] (WorkerThread#0[127.0.0.1:30606]) Failed to complete command: [start] for deployment: names=[group4_Implementation.ear]: org.jboss.profileservice.spi.NoSuchDeploymentException: group4_Implementation.ear
    at org.jboss.profileservice.plugins.deploy.AbstractDeployHandler.resolveProfileForDeployment(AbstractDeployHandler.java:291) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.plugins.deploy.AbstractDeployHandler.resolveProfiles(AbstractDeployHandler.java:248) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.plugins.deploy.AbstractDeployHandler.startDeployments(AbstractDeployHandler.java:157) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandlerDelegate.startDeployments(DeployHandlerDelegate.java:74) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandler.invoke(DeployHandler.java:156) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:967) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:791) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:744) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:548) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:234) [:6.1.0.Final]

2012-03-11 19:05:16,436 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] (HDScanner) deploy, ctxPath=/group4_Implementation-war
2012-03-11 19:05:16,469 WARN  [org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner] (HDScanner) Scan failed: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "persistence.unit:unitName=group4_Implementation.ear/group4_Implementation-ejb.jar#wvp08heuPU" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=POSTGRES-EJB,service=DataSourceBinding" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:name=POSTGRES-EJB,service=DataSourceBinding' **")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=POSTGRES-EJB,service=DataSourceBinding" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:name=POSTGRES-EJB,service=DataSourceBinding' **

    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1370) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1316) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:968) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:82) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.checkComplete(ProfileControllerContext.java:138) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.deploy(HDScanner.java:246) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.complete(HDScanner.java:192) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(TwoPCActionWrapper.java:57) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:135) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:146) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:90) [:0.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]

2012-03-11 19:05:21,516 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] (HDScanner) undeploy, ctxPath=/group4_Implementation-war
2012-03-11 19:05:21,703 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] (HDScanner) deploy, ctxPath=/group4_Implementation-war
2012-03-11 19:05:21,734 WARN  [org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner] (HDScanner) Scan failed: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "persistence.unit:unitName=group4_Implementation.ear/group4_Implementation-ejb.jar#wvp08heuPU" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=POSTGRES-EJB,service=DataSourceBinding" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:name=POSTGRES-EJB,service=DataSourceBinding' **")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=POSTGRES-EJB,service=DataSourceBinding" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:name=POSTGRES-EJB,service=DataSourceBinding' **

    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1370) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1316) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:968) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:82) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.checkComplete(ProfileControllerContext.java:138) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.deploy(HDScanner.java:246) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.complete(HDScanner.java:192) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(TwoPCActionWrapper.java:57) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:135) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:146) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:90) [:0.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_20]
```

My persistence unit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <!-- The name attribute gives the name that the persistence unit will have
  when it's loaded inside JBoss.
  This is what you use in the PersistenceContext annotation in your class.
  -->
  <persistence-unit name="wvp08heuPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <!-- This is a reference to the datasource that is used.
    By keeping this seperate it allow the container to pool database connections
    for you, improving performance. It also provide as extra layer of indirection
    allowing the details of the database to be kept seperate from this code.
    -->
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/POSTGRES-EJB</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have setup a datasource and it has confirmed a connection to the database.

Following tech not sure if it helps or not:

JBoss 6.1.0

Netbeans 7.1.1

Postgres: 8.4

Any help would be appreciated....

Lewis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create xml with configuration of DataSource `POSTGRES-EJB` in JBoss's folder *server/default/deploy*, or set configurations with the help of JBoss's admin console.

[More here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Connectors_on_JBoss-Configuring_JDBC_DataSources.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I managed to fix this just now before I saw your reply. Your correct of course - I managed to fix this by adding the datasource definition to the 'setup' folder of both my EJB module and in the overriding container within jboss-ds.xml - That seemed to solve my issue.

Comment: Oh as another side note you need to have the persistence provider JAR files in the server/default/deploy otherwise you will get a ClassNotFound error when using JBoss 6.1. Oh and another note EclipseLink JPA 2.0 dosen't seem to like JBoss 6.1 keep getting a Class Casting problem when it attempts to translate it to JBoss. I got around this by using TopLinks Essentials 1.0 as a provider.